# creating an algorithm for basic bit flipping

Tags: python, algorithm, bit, flip

```
def bit_flip(a):
    return ~a & 0xffffffff
t = (raw_input(""))
for i in range(0,t):
    a = t.split()
    a = bit(a)
    flip = bit_flip(a)
    print flip
```

and it gives me an error that says :

```
File "solution.py", line 4, in <module>
for i in range(0,t):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str
```

This code is for this problem:
**Problem Statement**

You will be given a list of 32-bits unsigned integers. You are required to output the list of the unsigned integers you get by flipping bits in its binary representation (i.e. unset bits must be set, and set bits must be unset).

**Sample Input**

3 
2147483647 
1 
0

**Sample Output**

2147483648 
4294967294 
4294967295

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is the messed up part. You should bring a lot of the stuff outside of the for loop. Let us examine your code:

```
t = (raw_input(""))
```

No need for parenthesis.

```
for i in range(0,t):
```

This makes no sense. What if the user inputed `"cat"` for `t`? Would it make sense to go from `0` to `"cat"`?. Instead, bring this:

```
    a = t.split()
    a = bit(a) #Should be int() not bit()
```

Out of the loop. (Also, we can't just say `int(a)` and expect all the items in the list to be converted to an `int`, we need to `map` it).

This gives us:

```
def bit_flip(a):
    return ~a & 0xffffffff

t = raw_input("")
a = map(int, t.split())
for i in a:
    print bit_flip(i)
```

Comment: The answer is supposed to be 
2147483648
4294967294
4294967295
However, the code suggestions that you made only gives
4294967292

Comment: @sanster9292: *Hint:* What is wrong with the first output? It shouldn't be too hard to change this code to make the program work.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use

```
map(lambda x: x ^ 0xffffffff, a)
```